# for each iteration generating error

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012

I am rebuilding my website from scratch having made substantial changes to the database. The following function worked perfectly fine in the old web site project but now that I've copied the code into the new project, VS2012 is not liking "order" in the For Each order in custorders, saying order is not declared and may not be accessible due to its protection level

```
Public Shared Function GetOrderDisplaybyCustomerId(ByVal customerId As Integer) As List(Of OrderDisplay)
    Dim list As New List(Of OrderDisplay)
    Dim item As New OrderDisplay
    Using ctx As New webEntities
        Dim custorders = (From o In ctx.salesorders
                         Where o.order_divisionId = customerId
                         Join s In ctx.addresses On o.order_shippingAddressId Equals s.addressId
                         Join st In ctx.states On s.address_stateProvinceId Equals st.stateId
                         Order By o.OrderDate Ascending
                         Select New With {o.OrderDate, o.InvoiceNumber, o.CustomerPONumber, o.AccountNumber, s.StreetAddress, s.City, st.AbbreviatedName}).ToList()
        If custorders.Count > 0 Then
            For Each order In custorders
                item._orderdate = order.OrderDate.ToShortDateString()
                item._invoicenumber = order.InvoiceNumber
                item._customerPOnumber = order.CustomerPONumber
                item._acctnumber = order.AccountNumber
                item.Address = order.StreetAddress
                item.City = order.City
                item.State = order.AbbreviatedName
                list.Add(item)
            Next
            Return list
        Else
            Return Nothing
        End If
    End Using
End Function
```

I'm getting this exact same behavior in other functions as well, any suggestions appreciated.

Comment: Why are you first creating an anonymous type, only to convert it immediately into a specific type (by re-using one instance - I expect that will give errors)? Why not create OrderDisplay entities in your LINQ query?

Comment: becaue changing Dim custorders to Dim custorders as List(Of OrderDisplay) generates an even more glaring error in VS. How would you go about that?

Comment: With the `.ToList()` you already have, I wouldn't expect errors if you return `OrderDisplay`s. I don't know enough VB to help you further though, sorry.

Comment: I also suggest you create a new item each time in the loop, right now, you are always inserting the same item. At the end, your list will contain a bunch of the same.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you have a global project level of setting:

```
Option Infer Off
```

Check it at your project settings to make sure `Option Infer On`, and then at your individual class/module file, make sure there is no `Option Infer Off`

Comment: Option Infer is set to on by default and I havent changed it

Comment: Option Infer is the only making i can think of that could cause that interesting error all the places. sorry i cannot think of anything else... perhaps you try to build the solution use MSBuild and see what the compiler would complain?